# CSS - centered image over a DIV with responsive background and full height image display

Tags: html, css, image, centering

If you reed carefully this question you'll note IT'S NOT A DUPLICATED QUESTION. This one is about an image over a responsive background with full height image display. The answers related to the other questions are useless here. Thanks to jacob for his simple solution.

The issue:

I have a DIV with a responsive background. I'm trying to place a centered png "logo" over the DIV (or the background, if you prefer). That's what I have:

```
.divWithBG {
    background-image: url(...);
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-top: 45.45%; /* (h/w) x 100 */
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.divWithBG img{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

¿What I need to do to place the image inside the div? Centered both, vertically and horizontally.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: can you use flex-box? It makes it extremely easy.

Comment: It's not a duplicated question, Kevin. It has a difference: responsive background (with full image height display)

Comment: why don't you just add the logo as a second background-image?

Comment: I'll check flexbox, Jacob. It looks nice and simple. Thanks!

Comment: As a second background-image? What do you mean Jacob?. I guess, the second background will inherit the same properties...

Comment: @Sergio here, I'll post an answer for the background image, it would be hard to explain in the comments :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just make it simpler and use 2 background images. [Multiple background images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multiple_backgrounds) in CSS:

```css
    .divWithBG {
        background-image: url("http://lorempizza.com/380/240") , url("http://lorempizza.com/2000/2000");
        background-size: 50%, contain;
        background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
        background-position:center;
        width: 100%;
        padding-top: 45.45%; /* (h/w) x 100 */
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="divWithBG"></div>
```

The background image you want to be on top comes first in the `background` property.

Comment: Works like a charm, Jacob.  Thanks, indeed!

Comment: @Sergio No problem, glad I could help!